# How to recreate a Pulse-like UI?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I was wondering how to make image display through a table like the application [Pulse](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pulse-news-reader/id371088673?mt=8) on iPhone. I used `UIScrollView` but it did not help much. It only displayed images in a nice array-like manner but you could not produce an event or click on the image.

What's the best way to produce a [Pulse](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pulse-news-reader/id371088673?mt=8) like application for displaying images and heading information in an array-like style?

Comment: Attache an image or a link to iTunes store, not everyone needs to know what Pulse app looks like

Comment: @user714469 take a look a this tutorial: http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/06/29/creating-pulse-style-scrolling-horizontally-scrolling-uitableview-as-a-subview-of-uitableviewcell/. If you find the solution to the asked question at the bottom of tutorial, let me know...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use Ray Wenderlich tutorial about THIS topic

[tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4680/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-1)

Answer (score 3):

The Ray Wenderlich pulse tutorial does have an issue where if the horizontal table view has not been scrolled (or its first element is aligned with the left of the screen) you can't drag right and have the content pull that way and then bounce back. This makes the scrolling experience feel pretty bad.

The simple solution though is to put the horizontal table view inside a scroll view and then everything just works.

Comment: Thanks, @EarlyRiser. I've been thinking how to fix this and finally found this, you are the man!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a `UITableView` with rows that are composed of `UIImageView`s. Its got a nice touch where you can scroll horizontally within a row, like with Twitter's app. That's most likely done with a `UIScrollView` (scroll bars removed, with end bounce). Peter Boctor wrote a [web blog post](http://idevrecipes.com/2011/04/14/how-does-the-twitter-iphone-app-implement-side-swiping-on-a-table/) on how to do something similar, if I recall.

Comment: You are wrong. Pulse uses one tableView rotated by -90 degreess inside another tableView.

Answer (score 1):

It's a UITableView with each row containing a UITableView that is rotated by 90°. The cells for the UITableView in each row are custom views that are likely either subclasses of UIImageView or just plain UIView.

Comment: That's wrong. You will have problem with scrolls and bouncing.

Comment: No, You're wrong. http://itunes.apple.com/de/podcast/10-hacks-to-go-from-idea-to/id395605774?i=88960658 "10 Hacks ..." 7:50 There the developers describe exactly how they've created that specific UI

Comment: @julian is right. Pulse uses one tableView for vertical scroll and one tableView (rotated by -90°) for horizontal scroll. I am just implementing such structure from this tutorial: http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/06/29/creating-pulse-style-scrolling-horizontally-scrolling-uitableview-as-a-subview-of-uitableviewcell/. I get pretty far and only have one problem with redrawing cells upon reloadTable. Has anyone solution?

Comment: I think I would consider using UIButton's for the table rows, with a custom image set as the button. That may make the code for getting the single tap touch event a bit easier.