# UIScrollView within ScrollView - ScrollBars not showing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, uiscrollview

**BackStory**

I am writing an ipad app which has images that scrolls horizontally using a UIScrollView. This works fine. Now for each image i need to have a UIScrollView which has some kind of text explaining the image. This would be a vertical scrollView. The vertical ScrollView appears but then the scrollbars dont appear. Any idea why? Code below :

```
CGRect scrollViewFrame = CGRectMake(760, 70, 205, 320);
UIScrollView * contentScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:scrollViewFrame];
[contentView addSubview:contentScrollView];
CGSize scrollViewContentSize = CGSizeMake(205, 100);
[contentScrollView setContentSize:scrollViewContentSize];
[contentScrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
contentScrollView.delegate = self;

UILabel *titleLable = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 205, 40)];
UILabel *subtitleLable = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 60, 205, 50)];
UITextView * mainContent = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 110, 205, 230)];

[titleLable setText:storyTitle];
[subtitleLable setText:storySubTitle];
[contentView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[mainContent setText:storyDescription];
```

Also the main scrolView is already added using Interface Builder and is working fine. Does wnyone know why this is happening?

Comment: See my example in my own post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723841/how-to-have-multiple-scrollviews-in-one-scrollview][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723841/how-to-have-multiple-scrollviews-in-one-scrollview

Comment: Does it work if you remove `[contentScrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];`?

Comment: You want this scrollview with text to be able to scroll vertically? In that case contentSize.height (in your case 100.0) should be bigger than scrollView.size.height (in your case 320.0). And yes, paging also doesn't make sense for this child-scrollview.

Comment: Did you try `[contentScrollView setScrollEnabled:YES]` and/ or `[contentScrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:YES]` / `[contentScrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:YES]`

Comment: @Inafiger : No removing that doesnt help

Comment: @rokjarc - Yes what you mentioned worked. HAPPY! :)

Comment: @AlexSalom those are all default values.

Comment: Glad to hear that. You can mark Son Nguyen's answer as correct :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scroll view only shows scroll-bar and allows user to scroll whenever content size larger than scroll view size, as I see in your code, scroll view size is (205, 320) while content size is only (205, 100).